# Extract onclick attribute using Jsoup

Tags: jsoup

I'm having trouble trying to parse the onclick value of an element.
Here is the case I am dealing with:

```
<button data-theme="xyz" onclick="link to somewhere"> filler text</button>
```

I am successfully parsing the document and am able to extract this button tag into an Element object. But I cant figure out how to get the onclick value from the Element object.

Answer (score 0):

For the above html tag specified in the question you want to access the `onclick` attribute of `button` tag you can use the above statements in `javascript`.

```
 var a = getElementsByTagName("button")[0].getAttribute("onclick");
```

This will get the `button` tag at first occuring position (ie; `index [0]`) in the html code and get its `onclick` attribute and returns it to `a` variable. In case if there is no `onclick` arrtibute mentioned then `null` is returned by default.

```
 document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0].setAttribute("onclick","fun()");
```

In this case you access the button-tag at first occuring position (ie; array index [0]) and set its `onclick="fun()"`.

Comment: I have just edit/update this answer and explained the getAttribute() and setAttribute() statements in relevance to the answer to make it understandable.

Comment: Im using this in an Android app so i need to use some Java library not javascript

Comment: Are you developing android app in java ?

Comment: Yes, Java. I just posted my solution. If your curious. You're method works but i needed it in Java. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So i came to this solution and it works to retrieve the value assigned to the onlick attribute. I think i may have just missed the documentation for the attr()
method. This is in java:

```
Jsoup.parse("URL goes here").getElementsByTag("button).attr("onclick");
```

For some reason the documentation led me to believe that the attr() method is only for setting a value to an attribute;